# Method Parameters and JSTL

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

What is the "items" attribute syntax for a method with a parameter that returns a list using JSTL? For instance if I have a method

```
List<String> fName = null;
public List<String> FirstName(String firstName)
{
    return firstName
}
```

and a JSP

```
<c:foreach var="something" items="fname">
    ${something}
</c:foreach>
```

How do I supply the method with the Parameter?

Thank you.

Comment: You can not call method in a c:forEach tag. It is used basically to iterate over a collection. I think JSTL does not support calling java methods directly from the JSP. There is no such tags in JSTL to do this. If you need to call java method from the JSP, you should look into Ajax or may be DWR.

Comment: @Ashish Thanks. I've changed by code snippet to be a little more readable. I'm passing the list into a c:foreach and it would work fine if I didn't need a parameter on the method. Are you familiar with making this work if the method had a parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't make much sense. There is something wrong in the flow. You should prepare exactly the list the JSP needs in the servlet.

```
List<String> firstNames = something.list(firstName);
request.setAttribute("firstNames", firstNames);
request.getRequestDispatcher("result.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

and then

```
<c:forEach items="${firstNames}" var="firstName">
    ${firstName}<br/>
</c:forEach>
```

The list can of course be a bean property, but to the point, you just need to make sure that exactly the list you want to display is *already* been prepared in the servlet so that JSP EL just have to get it as a bean property.

---

Unrelated to the concrete problem, in JSP/EL 2.2 (along Servlet 3.0) it's possible to pass arguments to bean methods, but this is definitely not the right solution in your particular case.

Comment: Thanks for you help. My issue was that I was trying to send the list to the JSP prior to preparing it. I figure it out later that day, but your post help me realize that I was correct in what I "figured out". Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

How do you pass the variable to your jstl?

If your process this in a single page. This is an example

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1" %>
<%@ page isELIgnored="false" %>
<%@ page import="java.util.ArrayList" %>
<%@ page import="java.util.List;" %>
<% 
    List<String> xList = new ArrayList<String>();

    xList.add("a");
    xList.add("b");
    xList.add("c");

    pageContext.setAttribute("sList", xList);
%>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <c:forEach var="lst" items="${sList}">
        <span>${lst}</span>
    </c:forEach>

</body>
</html>
```

Note: you should know the good programming practice. What I post is just a sample where the foreach print the value. The variable maybe come from a sevlet.

EDITED:
Passing variable value from servlet to jsp. Inside your servlet it could be in do post or do get or other function which have the HttpServletRequest/HttpServletResponse

```
request.setAttribute("sList", xList);
request.getRequestDispatcher("your.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

Comment: I have basic knowledge of programming, and it's a method in a servlet that I'm having an issue with. The method takes a parameter and returns a list so I'm not certain if the syntax in the c:foreach is supposed to be different than what you typed in your answer. thanks.

Comment: Yes it is the same way. The problem maybe is how you pass the variable value to your jsp page. See the edited post. If the process of calling your jsp page is different with my example, please let me know.

Comment: Thank you for you help. I needed to prepare the servlet before sending it to the JSP and then I could use the request.set/getattribute.